# jQuery - Select everything on a page except one div

Tags: jquery, background, popup, fade

How can I select each and everything on a page except a particular div using jQuery?

Actually I am trying to fade the rest of background on popup of a particular div. 
But the problem is that not everything is inside some div. **Few elements don't have any parent div.**

```
<body>
    12345

    <div id='second_div'>
       XXXXXX
    </div>

    56789

    <div id='popup'>
       AAAAA
    </div>
</body>
```

I am using code below but this is **not fading content which don't have a parent div**(i.e 12345 and 56789). It is only fading content of 'second_div'(i.e. XXXXXX ).

```
$('body > div:not(#popup)').css("opacity",'0.7');
```

Please guide me on how to do this using jQuery.

Comment: Why not just add one div as an overlay and then position your special modal div above it with a higher z-index?

Comment: You need to wrap it before you tap i... er before you fade it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
$("body > *").not('#popup').css("opacity", '0.7');
```

The reason this works is because it selects all the direct descendants of `body` and then removes all direct descendants that have an `id` of `popup`.

Comment: I just re-read the question. I was under the impression that the unwrapped text was not supposed to "dim". In that case the only solution is to wrap them in something like a `div` or `p`.

Answer (score 1):

Tested it and works perfectly, although I've tested the other one and it doesn't but anyway, good luck!

```
var lines = $('body').html().split('\n');
$.each(lines, function(k, v){
  lines[k] = '<span>'+v+'</span>';
});

$('body').html(lines.join(''));

$('body > *').css("opacity", '0.7').find('#popup').parent().css("opacity", '1');
;
```