# jQuery - Select everything but

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want to use jQuery to select everything on a page except a certain `div`. My question is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7938274/2317532), but that solution selects only divs, I want to select ***everything***.

In this [example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/padxaupu/6/), I want to select everything that does not have, or not the descendent of an element with, a class of "kids". So clicking on the "grandkids" and "kids" should not show a log entry, but clicking on the "parent" or the image would.

The page will have a very complex structure so something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10506138/2317532) wouldn't be feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code, this code exclude `.kids` element and inner elements of `.kids` class

```
$('body').click(function(e) {
    if(!$(e.target).closest('.kids').length){
      console.log(e.target);
    }
});
```

## DEMO

Comment: Thank you @Girish, this is exactly what I am looking for! Just wondering (out of curiosity) if there's an equivalent way using selectors only? (no if statements, just selectors)

Comment: @dayuloli no way to prevent outside event from one selector, `:not()` function work on selected element but it can't prevent from `not(<selector>)` inner elements

Answer (score 2):

You can try the not selector

```
$('body *').not('.kids, .kids *');
```

or if you are trying to register an event handler then

```
$(document).on('click', ':not(.kids, .kids *)', function(){
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I tried this also. But it's still showing up. http://jsfiddle.net/padxaupu/7/

Comment: thanks for your updated answer. It works perfectly! But I've accepted Girish's answer because he posted the same answer first. Thanks for your help nonetheless

Comment: Accepted... comment withdraw. Add that JSFiddle to your answer. Please keep the upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `e.currentTarget` in jquery

```
$("#parent").not($('.kids')).click(function(e) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, using `currentTarget` will still trigger when the "kids" divs are clicked. I want it so that when the "kids" or "grandkids" divs are clicked, nothing returns on the console. Also, I want everything on the page to be selected, not just what is inside the "parent" div....http://jsfiddle.net/padxaupu/8/